# Series of Monotone Decreasing Functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $u_n$ be sequence of functions from an arbitrary set $\Omega$ to the real numbers such that $\big\{u_n(x) \neq 0\big\}$ is finite for each n.

Suppose that $u_n \geq u_{n+1}$ and $\inf_{n}u_n(x)=0$. Prove that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{u_n(x)\neq 0}u_n(x) =0$$
I am unsure how to approach this problem. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the first sentence, do you mean to say that $\{ u_n(x) \neq 0 \}$ is finite for each $n$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Hint: the quantity $\sum_{x : u_n(x) \neq 0} u_n(x)$ is decreasing in $n$, and bounded below by $0$.  So you just need to show that it can't be bounded below by any positive number

Comment: Could we argue that if it were bounded below by a positive number, then our infimum condition would be violated?

Comment: I think so, although I'd say it requires a bit of explaining why

Comment: Actually, if we know that $\inf_n u_n(x) = 0$, and $\big\{u_n(x) \neq 0\big\}$ is finite, wouldn't $u_n$ be identically zero for every $n$?

Comment: No, not necessarily

Comment: This is an immediate consequence of DCT with dominating function $u_1$.

Comment: I was able to put together an answer. Thank you @Adam.